# Jquery UI Spinner - Disable Keyboard Input

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

Im trying to find away to stop a user using the keyboard to input values via jquery ui spinners.  I have several spinners and would like it to only allow the user to use the up and down arrows to increase or decrease the value.

Ive tried looking round stackoverflow and google and cant seem to find somethign that works.

So I have for example and input like this:

```
<input type="text" class="spinner" value="10"/>
```

and initialise the spinner like this:

```
$(".spinner").spinner();
```

and then try to disable keypress like this:

```
$(".spinner").unbind("keypress");
```

and it still allows keyboard input.  Does anyone know away to do this?
Heres a JSBin file that Ive been testing with: http://jsbin.com/ujajab/1/edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple! Replace

```
$(".spinner").unbind("keypress");
```

with

```
$(".spinner").bind("keydown", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Unbind will just unbind the functions that have been binded. A textfields default behavior wont be changed; so we have to prevent that! If you don't want it to focus at all:

```
$(".spinner").focus(function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: haha cheers dude, I thought Id tried that...obviously not  =D  works a treat thank you  =D

Comment: In my case, keydown is not working as I have made readonly that spinner input box but blur works for me. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work if you're dynamically adding the input with the spinner.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply add readonly attribute to your  label like this:

```
<input type="text" class="spinner" value="10" readonly/>
```

this works for me! 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One may want to avoid unbinding and prefer using the existing API's onchange callback:

[jquery UI Spinner change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change)

Discard the change if out of your boundaries.