# Disabling keyboard input also disables spinner value incrementing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery-ui spinner widget that I would like to disable keyboard input and focus so that the user cannot enter an invalid value. Searching stackoverflow I followed the excellent example provided by Leonard Pauli (thanks for that btw! :) here [Jquery UI Spinner - Disable Keyboard Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922215/jquery-ui-spinner-disable-keyboard-input)

It seems that when keyboard access is removed and the widget is blurred the spinner loses the feature of incrementing when the mouse button is held down on the arrows. It still increments on click, but will not auto increment when held down.

Below is a simple example of the keyboard disabling and blurring or the spinner. Also a fiddle of this example here http://jsfiddle.net/LCxHB/

```
$("#spin").spinner(
{
    min: 0,
    max: 999
});

$("#spin").focus(function() {
    $("#spin").blur();
});

$("#spin").bind("keydown",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

I am pretty new to jquery-ui so I am hoping there is something simple I am missing. The existing functionality is 'almost' OK for me but it would be nice to allow for incrementing values when the mouse button is held down.

Comment: Weird, I can increment values when holding down the mouse button. I just removed all your tags except input, set jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 on your fiddle and it works.

Comment: Thank you candeias ... works perfectly as you suggest -you are a legend. I really appreciate your input on this - such a simple solution but one that had me poking around for hours.